# Period in C# classes and Structs

Tags: c#, oop

I keep seeing a period (.) in the classes and structs of c#. For example in `JsonElement.ArrayEnumerator` and `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.ValueCollection:`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.valuecollection?view=net-8.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.arrayenumerator?view=net-8.0

Does this mean it's a nested class in that particular class, or part of the JsonElement namespace, or is this simply legal to have a period in the definition of a class or struct?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types

Comment: I don't see the definition for the JsonElement.ArrayEnumerator struct in the definition for JsonElement though:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement?view=net-8.0

Comment: WHICH period, I see two.

Comment: Periods might also be inside a namespace like `Karl.Person.GoodPeople` which has no other meaning outside of that

Comment: Hello @MarkSchultheiss thanks I get it now. The JsonElement.ArrayEnumerator class was just not indented in the documentation lol that's why I wasn't coming to that conclusion

Comment: That's because a public nested type is distinct from it's outer type from a consumers perspective. It only differs from an authors perspective, which is why it has its own documentation page.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a [nested type](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types). Essentially it behaves very similar to an additional namespace. In addition you can access the `static` members of the enclosing class:

```
class Enclosing
{
    private static int MyStaticMember;
    private int NonStaticMember;
    class Nested 
    { 
        void DoSomething() 
        { 
            MyStaticMember = -1; // access private static member of enclosing type here
            NonStaticMember = -1; // cannot access non-static members
        }
    }
}
```

There are a few things to consider, when thinking about using a nested type instead of a namespace. First off you can't use the enclosing type where a namespace is expected, e.g. in a `using`-directive. So the following won't compile:

```
public class Enclosing
{
    public class Nested { }
}
...

using Enclosing;
public class MyClasss
{
    Nested n = new Nested(); // compiler-error: the Type Nested was not found
}
```

You may use a `using static Enclosing`, though.

The second thing is, that while namespaces don't have any concept of visibility, classes do, and so do nested classes. So the nested types visibility may be restricted by the enclsoing types visibility, e.g.

```
private class Enclosing
{
    public class Nested { ... }
}
```

As the enclosing class is private, the `Nested` class is only accessible within that single class, which makes sense for internal data-structures that are only used within that class.

Comment: You can use a `using` directive, it's just that the [static modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#static-modifier) is required i.e. `using static Enclosing;`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay  yeap, thanks for pointing that out, you're absolutelly right.

Comment: Also, you need to make `Nested` public in your example, or else it wont be accessible outside of `Enclosing`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay which is the point of my 3rd example.

Comment: No, the point is that `Nested` is inaccessible outside of `Enclosed`, even within the same assembly. That's because, like other members, it defaults to private, meaning that you could not reference it in `MyClass` even with a `static using` or fully qualified name.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I already updated my econd example to reflect that.

Comment: I'm referring to the first example, where `Nested` lacks an access modifier.

Comment: The second example doesn't really make sense either. You can't have a private class, unless it itself is a nested type, and in that case, `Nested` _would_ still be visible to the outer type: https://dotnetfiddle.net/29Nn7q.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay You got me whrong, the second example is about the `using`-directive, not about visibility - which is the point of the 3rd example.

Comment: Furthermor the first eample isn't about accessing `Nested` *oudside*  `Enclosing`. I still don't get you.

Answer (score -1):

The `.` can mean different things in C#. In a class name, it's usually the *namespace* the class is in. The class `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<T1, T2>` is in the namespace `System.Collections.Generic`. The namespace is part of the class name, but can be left away with an `using` declaration in a source file.

For nested classes, the period is also used. The `.ValueCollection` is a sub-type (the documentation uses the term "nested type") of the Dictionary, so it also uses a period to denote that type.